App Widget To Add On Home And Lock Screen Automatically when the app installs
I want my android app widget to be added on the home screen or lock screen, as my android app gets downloaded.
I tried passing the adb commands but not any command worked. Is there any way to add this feature into my android application, when it gets installed, the app widget automatically gets added into the home screen or lock screen.


Is there any way to add this feature into my android application, when it gets installed, the app widget automatically gets added into the home screen or lock screen.

No.
Note that lock screen widgets have not been supported by Android in quite some time, though they may be coming back to tablets for Android 15. Also note that users do not need to use a launcher app that supports app widgets, and many Android environments do not support app widgets at all (e.g., watches, TVs, cars, Chrome OS devices).

Thank you! this is what I feel is the most important is many Android environments do not support app widgets at all.
